# evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x-1}{\ln x}dx$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x-1}{\ln x}dx$,where x is real.

Approach:

The suggestion is to differentiate $H(m)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{m}-1}{\ln x}dx$. This leads to

$$H(m)'=m\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{m-1}}{\ln x}dx, $$

$$H(m)''=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{m-1}}{\ln x}dx+m(m-1)\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{m-2}}{\ln x}dx$$

...

Comment: What is the question? :)

Comment: The notation suggests you need to be taking the derivative with respect to $m$

Comment: See also: [Prove $\int_{0}^1\frac{x-1}{\log x}dx=\log 2$ and $\int_{0}^1\frac{\log x}{x-1}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/461245) and [Why does $\int\limits_0^1 {\dfrac{{x - 1}}{{\ln x}}} \;\text{d}x=\ln2$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/438802)

Answer (score 5):

The hint is very good. Let $$\eta(s)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^s-1}{\log x}dx$$ Then $$\eta'(s)=\int_0^1 \log x\frac{x^{s}}{\log x}dx=\int_0^1  {x^{s}} dx$$

Comment: how did you get the second log(x)?

Comment: @TKM $\dfrac{d}{ds}(x^s-1)=x^s\log x$.

Comment: thanks i got my variables swapped.